# Chrome DevTools shows only part of a file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I open Chrome Devtools in order to debug a script, it shows only a small portion of the script.

The file itself is about 30,000 lines of code, when the app runs for the first time, Devtools only show about 9600 rows, when I refresh, it shows only 19 lines.

I couldn't find any solution online, have you ever encountered this kind of problem? 
Do you have an idea why it happens?

Comment: maybe because such a huge file is ridiculous?

Comment: @Alex Not really. Have you ever used browserify with babel?

Comment: @Sulthan no but require :)

Comment: Perhaps you can use sourcemaps as part of your build process in order to view the files "split out" in devtools?

Comment: @Alex - Like Sulthan said, try working with browserify, react and babel :)

There are sourcemaps, but the problem is that there's another framework that takes my files and bundles them once more.